# Heatmap (geom_tile) produces dark bars overlaying plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a heatmap using ggplot to show a changing value over time. The majority of my plot is covered by large black bars. How can I remove these bars to see only the red and green?

[image: plot]

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(dmy_hm("12/04/2020 12:00"), dmy_hm("12/04/2020 13:00"), "5 min"),
                   bund = as.factor("P1"),
                   inflow = (rnorm(13)))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = datetime, y = bund,  colour = inflow)) + 
  geom_tile(height = 0.9) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", high = "green", midpoint = 0)

plot
```

Comment: Use the `fill` aesthetic instead of the `colour`, would that help?

Comment: @teunbrand yes that's worked, thank-you.